# MySQL how to group by and select certain status from multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

A credit card company has several credit cards issued to each consumer.

```
CREATE TABLE card (
  cardnumber int PRIMARY KEY,
  customer int,
  balance decimal(9,2),               
  status varchar(10)              
);

INSERT INTO card VALUES ('100', '1', 100.00, 'active');
INSERT INTO card VALUES ('101', '1', 100.00, 'expired');
INSERT INTO card VALUES ('102', '2', 100.00, 'limited');
INSERT INTO card VALUES ('103', '2', 100.00, 'locked');
INSERT INTO card VALUES ('104', '3', 100.00, 'lost');
INSERT INTO card VALUES ('105', '3', 100.00, 'closed');
```

A report is desired consisting of one row per cardholder, total balance on all cards, and the least restrictive status in the exact order of: 1. Active, 2. Expired, 3. Limited, 4. Locked, 5. Lost, 6. Closed.

Cardholder #1 has a card in 'active', and a card in 'expired', the report should show 'active'.
Cardholder #2 has a card in 'limited', and a card in 'locked', the report should show 'limited'.
Cardholder #3 has a card in 'lost', and a card in 'closed', the report should show 'lost'.

It appears it would be helpful to have another table for status

```
create table status (
  status varchar(15) primary key,
  restriction int
);

insert into status values ('active', 1);
insert into status values ('expired', 2);
insert into status values ('limited', 3);
insert into status values ('locked', 4);
insert into status values ('lost', 5);
insert into status values ('closed', 6);
```

How can the query show only the least restrictive status of the cardholders cards?

```
select c.customer, sum(c.balance), 'status?'
from card c
join status s on s.status=c.status?
group by c.customer
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d680/2

PS Table #1 'card' cannot be changed.

Comment: Hint:  the least restrictive is going to be the minimum of `restriction` in the `status` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a derived table containing the minimum restriction for each customer and then join the minimum restriction to the status table.

```
select t1.*, s.status from (
    select c.customer, sum(c.balance), min(restriction) min_restriction
    from card c
    join status s on s.status=c.status
    group by c.customer
) t1 join status s on t1.min_restriction = s.restriction
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d680/3

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the report even not to create the second table

```
    select customer,sum(balance),
    min(restriction),case
    when min(restriction)=1 then 'active'
    when min(restriction)=2 then 'expired'
    when min(restriction)=3 then 'limited'
    when min(restriction)=4 then 'locked'
    else 'lost'
    end stat
    from (
    select cardnumber,customer,balance,status,case
    when status='active' then 1
    when status='expired' then 2
    when status='limited' then 3
    when status='locked' then 4
    when status='lost' then 5
    else 6
    end restriction
    from card  ) c
    group by 
    customer
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/898bd/5

MySQL has some advantages out of  RDMS standard.